# How solve internet explorer cannot open site http://www.xyz.com/map.htm operation aborted?

Tags: google-maps

I have used google map. When i go to link www.xyz.com/view_map.html no problem for firefox but for IE error message is displayed like this (internet explorer cannot open site http://www.xyz.com/view_map.html operation aborted). Is there any solution for this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please elaborate on the error message.

Comment: This question is not on topic of a programming forum. (Or your question fails to make clear why this is a programming question.) Plus your question lack sufficient data to answer the question.

Please try the IE help desk.

Comment: Hi Don & Ganesh, this IS the elaborated error message. This message appears, and *WHAM* - IE 6 shows an error page. This may be due to code written in a particular manner. And this is programming related.

To disable this in IE6, you can turn off friendly HTTP error messages in Internet Explorer.

To do this, follow these steps - 1) On the Tools menu, click Internet Options. 2) On the Advanced tab, click to clear the Show friendly HTTP error messages check box under the Browsing section, and then click OK. 3) Close the browser.

Comment: You can check out my answer of how this behaviour can be regenerated.

Comment: This will generate the "Operation Aborted" error in IE6 only.

Answer (score 3):

> This problem occurs because a child
>   container HTML element contains script
>   that tries to modify the parent
>   container element of the child
>   container. The script tries to modify
>   the parent container element by using
>   either the innerHTML method or the
>   appendChild method.
>
> For example, this problem may occur if
>   a DIV element is a child container in
>   a BODY element, and a SCRIPT block in
>   the DIV element tries to modify the
>   BODY element that is a parent
>   container for the DIV element.
>
> To work around this problem, write
>   script blocks that modify only closed
>   containers or that modify only the
>   script's immediate container element.
>   To do this, you can use a placeholder
>   to close the target container, or you
>   can move the script block into the
>   container that you want to modify.

To regenerate this behavior, you can do this -

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function appendToBody() {
                var span = document.createElement('span');
                document.body.appendChild(span);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                appendToBody();
            </script>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Reference: [KB Support Article #927917](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927917) & [Dealing with IE "Operation Aborted"](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/11/02/Dealing-with-IE-_2600_quot_3B00_Operation-Aborted_2600_quot_3B002E00_-Or_2C00_-how-to-Crash-IE.aspx).